# WP_Query->post_name returns null

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the post_name attribute from `WP_Query($args)` function in wordpress. If I'm using `var_dump($wp_query);` it shows me that the `post_name` attribute is not empty or null. It is the title of the post.

But if I'm trying to echo it using `echo $wp_query->post_name;` it returns an empty string.

This is how I define `$wp_query`:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'tag' => 'General');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

There are some posts which has the tag "General" so this cannot be the reason.

Can someone please explain that behaviour or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `$wp_query` isn't a single post, but all the posts that match the query args. This means you have to loop over the posts in the query result in some way. For instance, you can do something like this:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'tag' => 'General');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Get the posts from the query
$posts = $wp_query->get_posts();

// Loop through the posts
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    echo $post->post_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'tag' => 'General');

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Reference: [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0):

`post_name` and `post_title` are two different things.

`post_title` is the post's title whereas `post_name` is the post's unique part of the permalink - also known as the slug.

Instead of using

```
echo $wp_query->post_name;
```

use:

```
echo $wp_query->post_title;
```